Ignore file extension except in a specific directory in `.gitignore`
In my repository, I have scripts that generate loads of .json files, that I want to ignore, so I have *.json in .gitignore. But I have one directory config containing .json files and I want those to be in version control. I know I can run git add -f config/*.json, but is there any solution using only .gitignore to override the previous rules, so that git sees these files automatically without me needing to manually run git add -f ...?
I have tried these, but none worked:
*.json

!configs
!configs/
!configs/*
!configs/*.json

EDIT: to clarify, both .gitignore and the configs directory are both at the the top level of the repository. The structure looks something like this:
repo/
├─ .gitignore
├─ config/
│  ├─ keep_this_1.json
│  ├─ keep_this_2.json
├─ scripts/
│  ├─ results/
│  │  ├─ d1/
│  │  │  ├─ ignore_this.json
│  │  ├─ d2/
│  │  │  ├─ ignore_this_too.json


Single line !configs/*.json should work. If it doesn't run git check-ignore -v configs/*.json to see why the're ignored.

As mentioned in the question, I tried !configs/*.json and it didn't work. git check-ignore -v configs/*.json returns .gitignore:11:!configs/*.json   configs/*.json - I'm not sure entirely what that means

The first column is the applied rule: file, line number, the rule. The second column is the ignored file. configs/*.json in the second column unexpanded which means you don't have any configs/*.json file to unignore. ls -l configs/*.json ?

$ ls config coord.json  k3_copy.json  k3.json  k5.json  sigprod.json - currently k3_copy.json is untracked and ignored

It's config damn it, not configs!

Update
After seeing the update to your question post, it seems like that your exclusions, and the ones suggested in the answers, did not work due to a typo.
In fact, the original exclusion patterns refer to a configs folder, while in your directory structure and screenshot, the interested folder appears to be actually called config (without a trailing s).
Since both the .gitignore and the config folder are on the same level, you can make the rules work with just the two following patterns:
*.json
!config/*.json


Original Answer
The exclusion !configs/*.json would work only if the .gitignore and the configs folder are at the same directory level. In fact, quoting the Pattern Format section of the gitignore documentation:

If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.

This means that if the .gitignore file is defined in the root level of your working directory, while configs is in a subdirectory, you need to either provide the path to configs relatively from the .gitignore:
*.json
!path/relative/from/gitignore/to/configs/*.json

or use the double asterisk to make the pattern match across multiple directory levels:
*.json
!**/configs/*.json

However, this second rule will exclude the json content of any configs directory in your project. Therefore, if you need to exclude only the json files of a particular configs folder, this exclusion won't do it. The previous rule is most likely what you need in this scenario.

Just for completeness, I've listed the behavior of each one of your exclusions to better understand what was going on:
*.json

!configs          # excludes both files and directories named configs at any level below the .gitignore
!configs/         # excludes only directories named configs at any level  below the .gitignore
!configs/*        # excludes any content of a directory named configs at the same level of the current .gitignore
!configs/*.json   # excludes any json file in a directory named configs at the same level of the current .gitignore


I added an update to the question to clarify that config is in the top level of the repository - I also tried your !**/configs/*.json suggestion, but it didn't work

@JakeLevi you have a typo in your paths! You have written configs in your question, but in both your comment and the new update you referred to your folder as config (without a trailing s). If your folder is called config, you should update your exclusions to !path/relative/from/gitignore/to/config/*.json or !**/configs/*.json

... Oh dear. Can confirm !config/*.json in top-level .gitignore does work. I feel rather silly :)

@JakeLevi no worries :) happens to the bests too :D

You need to combine patterns to get specific in subdirectories. Say git help ignore for the full specs, I think the relevant bits include:  a leading or embedded / anchors the pattern at the .gitignore file's level, a trailing / marks the pattern as a directory-only exclusion, and excluding a directory summarily excludes its entire contents, the only way to even look there is to not exclude that directory.
I generally recommend just putting !*/ at the end of a .gitignore followed by any whole-directory exclusions you really wanted, that works really really well until the work tree structure starts getting remarkable.
!*/
!**/configs/*.json

and the last line there doesn't have to be at the end, stare at the git help ignore (add --web on the commandline for a browser version, the option should really read --browser, it uses locally-installed html) until you understand why. It may help to say Git gets the "later rules override" effect  by reading the (assembled from multiple sources) rules backwards and takes the first match it encounters.
I expect someone who knows "the canonical answer" for this offhand will be along shortly to close it as a dup of that, that's fine with me.

!*/ and !**/configs/*.json un-ignored 39 files I want to still ignore, but not the config/*.json files that I want to keep! BTW, I added an update to the question to clarify that config is in the top level of the repository

EDIT: as pointed out by @dani-vta , I made a typo in my question and in .gitignore. The directory is called config, but I was using configs in .gitignore. Simply using !config/*.json solves the problem. The other solutions below both work as well.

I found 2 solutions to this problem:
The first is to modify the original .gitignore, and replace *.json with scripts/results/**/*.json, so the pattern only applies to the .json files I want to ignore, and doesn't ignore the .json files I want to keep in the configs folder.
The second is to add an additional config/.gitignore file, which contains the single line !*.json, which successfully cancels out the *.json line in the top-level .gitignore file.
